# iptables: what's the best way to block hackers attacking our site via our CDN IP address

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, cdn

We are using **fail2iban** on **Ubuntu 18** to detect bad login attempts and ban the IP addresses which try too many times. We use **iptables** for the IP blocking.

After using it for a while we noticed that some of the bans do not work - some IP addresses are banned properly while some are allowed to make more login attempts and nothing seems to stop them.

Did anybody experience strange issues with iptables like his? I see many tickets about iptables not working at all, but our issue is different - wast majority of the blocking works and only some small amount of it fails.

The issue is not with fail2ban. We log `iptables -vnL` every minute to make sure the IP addresses do not disappear from the list for no reason.

A.B. made a great suggestion that because we use iptables with REJECT the attacker might be using an already established connection to send in more bad requests. So we adjusted the rules to use DROP.

But the issue is still not fixed. We noticed bad requests coming from 2.58.149.35 which was on the list of at least a couple of days.

This is how the rules in iptables look like (`iptables -vnL`):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 66 packets, 3358 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  37M  131G f2b-fv-dos  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 0:65535
  14M 1466M f2b-wordpress  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
  14M 1467M f2b-waf    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
  14M 1476M f2b-repeated  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
 238M  821G ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 238M  821G ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 201K  657M ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 199K  657M ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 199K  657M ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 199K  657M ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 47 packets, 4596 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 237M 1038G ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 237M 1038G ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 845K  798M ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 845K  798M ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 845K  798M ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 845K  798M ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-fv-dos (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  37M  131G RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-repeated (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                    
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       187.54.60.43         0.0.0.0/0           
  14M 1475M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-waf (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   30  1520 DROP       all  --  *      *       2.58.149.35          0.0.0.0/0           
  14M 1467M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-wordpress (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  14M 1466M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  830 64740 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
   14   632 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
  590 30068 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  99M  534G ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  61M   20G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
34209 1913K ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
34209 1913K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
11833  788K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
2074K  122M ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
2074K  122M ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  99M  534G ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  62M  194G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 499K   35M ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
2074K  122M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1434 95440 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 177K   13M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
 309K   20M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  786 46748 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
53508 3142K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
 475K   28M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       89.173.195.48        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       89.173.195.48        0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3306
  702 28308 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 49152:65534
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       89.173.200.197       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       89.173.200.197       0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       46.101.206.200       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       46.101.206.200       0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
  234  288K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443
   48  2752 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       54.39.160.178        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       54.39.160.178        0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3306
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       45.33.124.193        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       185.93.3.241         0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       209.58.131.100       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       188.167.252.65       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       188.167.252.65       0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3306
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       139.215.2.66         0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       10.11.12.14          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

The above list of rules is shortened, we have many other IP addresses on the list, but I ensured the structure is kept intact.

- IP 187.54.60.43 is an example of an IP ban which works properly
- IP 2.58.149.35 is somehow able to send in more requests although it uses same kind of DROP rule to get blocked

---

Update 2022-06-13: We found these bad requests which are let through are coming in via the CDN. Can the **original IP behind the CDN** be properly blocked using iptables?

---

Update 2022-06-20: We only allowed **specific file types** on our CDN. That's surely a lot simpler than any kind of firewall that can check the HTTP headers to figure out what is the original IP behind the CDN request.

Comment: Currently: If a connection stays established (including udp: it's about Netfilter's meaning of established) when the ban lands then if the application protocol inside allows multiple session attempts though this single connection, such attempts are still possible.

Comment: No. In the INPUT chain the f2b chains are called before the ufw-before-input chain which contains the rule allowing ESTABLISHED and RELATED packets.